# I have filled every field but still showing SQLSTATE[HY000] in user table in laravel why?

Tags: php, laravel

I have filled every required field in users table but still getting that error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'profession' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Tushar Saha, test@email.com, $2y$10$LDoHlFMH6irkn4riSaAA6evH.BxBw77HBKtluIAAn/gE2R9OmXfKy, 2019-02-08 13:13:25, 2019-02-08 13:13:25))
```

Arguments:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'profession' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Tushar Saha, test@email.com, $2y$10$LDoHlFMH6irkn4riSaAA6evH.BxBw77HBKtluIAAn/gE2R9OmXfKy, 2019-02-08 13:13:25, 2019-02-08 13:13:25))
```

I have double checked the ***profession*** spelling

1. In the migration folder
2. in view page
3. in register controller

I also check the posted values in network section:

```
_token  
"D9UB2NCdncIsorcsqmJGiy2QJZq0D5YSirnbBz5W"
name    "Tushar Saha"

profession  "Student"

email   "test@email.com"

password    "111111"

password_confirmation   "111111"
```

RegisterController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'profession' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

In migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('profession');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->tinyInteger('role')->default('3');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In view

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="profession" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Profession') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                <select name="profession" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('profession') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('profession') }}" required autofocus>
                                    <option value="">Select One</option>
                                    <option value="Student">Student</option>
                                    <option value="Employed">Employed</option>
                                    <option value="Business Man">Business Man</option>
                                </select>

                                @if ($errors->has('profession'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('profession') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is the code to insert into user? Do also show the User model.

Comment: Show us the code where you insert data into a table.

Comment: can you post your User model - especially the protected $fillable = [];

Comment: A full view on controller file please.

Comment: Can you please show the code where you save the model? I guess at some point you're doing something like $user->save() ? We need to see that

Comment: thank you everyone ... the problem was in fillable in user model .. I forgot to check there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and help you, as you don't seem to be responding to anyone:

either:

'profession' is missing in your `protected $fillable` in your `User` model, it should look like this:

```
class CmsUser extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'profession', 'password',

...
}
```

or, your controller is incorrect, and missing something like

```
$user->profession = $request('profession')
```

Please provide more information

Comment: @TusharSaha what was the issue?

Comment: what you said ... i forgot to check fillable in user model

Comment: awesome! glad I could help :)